# although I had linked css file with my html file externally but its not working

Tags: html, css

I don't known why there is such error when I inspect it my browser it shows
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    css:1

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking it like this, you need to make sure your CSS file is in the same folder as your HTML, otherwise you need to specify a path to the file. For example `href="/assets/css/styles.css"`. Also check if your are importing the right file name (style / styles)